# Oracle APEX: Date Picker - How can I use apex page item values for the year range?

Tags: datepicker, oracle-apex

For Oracle APEX 'Date Picker' I'm trying to get the values for year range from page items. Date picker year range does say, "Supported Substitutions: Application, Page Items and System Variables".For instance rather than 2000:2010; I want P1_BEGIN_YEAR:P1_END_YEAR.

I tried P1240_BEGIN_DATE_RANGE:P1240_END_DATE_RANGE.

** update
solved - this worked just fine &P1240_BEGIN_DATE_RANGE.:&P1240_END_DATE_RANGE.

Comment: solved - this worked just fine &P1240_BEGIN_DATE_RANGE.:&P1240_END_DATE_RANGE.

Comment: Don't answer in comments. If you have solved the problem then you can (and should) write an answer to your own question.